# Creating classes and variable assignment

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to understand how classes work a bit better "under the hood" of python.

If I create a class `Foo` like so

```
class Foo:
    bar = True
```

`Foo` is then directly accessible, such as `print(Foo)` or `print(Foo.bar)`

However, if I dynamically create create a class and **don't set it to a variable** like so

```
type('Foo',(),{'bar':True})
```

If done in the interpreter it shows `<class '__main__.Foo'>`. However, when I try to print `Foo` it's undefined...`NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`

Does this mean that when a class is created the "traditional" way (the first Foo class above), that python automatically sets a variable for the class of the same name? Sort of like this

```
# I realize this is not valid, just to convey the idea
Foo = class Foo:
    bar = True
```

If so, then why doesn't python also create a variable named `Foo` set to class Foo when using `type()` to create it?

Comment: `type()` does not create a class

Comment: @roganjosh then why does `type('Foo',(),{'bar':True})` result in `<class '__main__.Foo'>`?

Comment: if you are familiar with anonymous inner classes in java, then it is the same thing, if you don't reference the newly created object (the class in this case) it is unfortunately lost.

Comment: @marsouf sorry, I'm not familiar with java anonymous inner classes. If creating a class in Python the first way I've shown (the "regular" way) sets it to a variable, is there a particular reason why creating one with `type` doesn't do the same? After all, it does show a class was created when you use terminal to create a class with `type`.

Comment: @roganjosh `type` can and absolutely does create classes, though it it not its most common use case.

Comment: @user1104854 Yes, the class definition is equivalent to `Foo = type('Foo',(),{'bar':True})`. With regards to why it doesn't create the class in your namespace. `type` is just a function, and you wouldn't expect any other function to create  new variable in your namespace, so why should `type` be special?

Comment: @dunes I was very wrong on this one. I'm not sure I understand the usefulness of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's compare your problem with function statements and lambdas (because they play the same role here), consider this function `f` :

```
def f ():
  return 1
```

the above snippet of code is not an expression at all, it is a python statement that creates a function named `f` returning `1` upon calling it.

let's now do the same thing, but in a different way :

```
f = lambda : 1
```

the above snippet of code is a python expression (an assignment) that assigns the symbol `f` to the lambda expression (which is our function) `lambda : 1`. if we didn't do the assignment, the lambda expression would be lost, it is the same as writing `>>> 1` in the python REPL and then trying after that to reference it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but your example is based on returning a literal, not a variable. I'm not disagreeing, because frankly I don't know the details, but using `type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))` returns a class with name Foo. Does that make a difference at all? I guess my confusion lies as to why using the traditional `class Foo:...` creates a class sets it to a variable, but just using `type` will create a class but let it get picked up by the garbage collector.

Comment: consider this function call `type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))` as creating a new object (in thise case, the object represents a newly created type which we named `X`), if we don't give this object a name (a reference to it), it is simply lost.

Comment: Thanks. So basically we're given direct access to python's way of creating classes, but technically requires more involvement from us because we're now required to set it to a variable? Just seems weird that I can create a class called Bar, but all references to it must be using Foo, using `Foo = type('Bar',(),{})`

Comment: `type('Bar',(),{})` defines a new type whose `name` property is set to `'Bar'`, in your example `Foo` is just a name (a variable) pointing to the newly created type whose name again is `'Bar'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `type` with 3 argument is analogous to using the `lambda` to create a function.  Without assignment the evaluated expression is garbage collected.

However, just you can still create an instance of the class, just like you can immediately call a lambda function.

```
>>> lambda x: True
<function <lambda> at 0x0000022FF95AB598>
>>> type('Test', (), {'x': True})
<class '__main__.Test'>
```

You can also create an instance of the class, just like you can immediately call a function

```
>>> t = type('Test', (), {'x': True})()
>>> t.x
True
>>> type('Test2', (), {'y': 123})().y
123
>>> (lambda x: True)(1000)  # any input returns True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

> class **type**(name, bases, dict)
>
> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The name string is the class name and becomes the **name** attribute; the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the **bases** attribute; and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the **dict** attribute. For example, the following two statements create identical type objects:

```
class X(object):
    a = 1
X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

So yes, I think you have the right idea. `type()` does create a class but a dynamic form.

Comment: the type `X` is created upon calling the function `type`, not when assigning the result of the function `type` to some name (in this example `X`)

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this too complicated. If you don't assign a value / object to a symbol, it is always "lost". Doesn't matter if the value / object is a class or something else. Example:

```
x = 2 + 2
```

That assigns the value `4` to the symbol `x`. Compare to:

```
2 + 2
```

The operation is carried out but the result `4` isn't assigned to a symbol.

Exact situation you have with classes.